# ADB doesn't recognize grep and wfi command and doesn't connect to LTE device

Tags: shell, adb, android-things

I am having a problem connecting to my [LTE device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiPSz.jpg).

After executing my command of connecting to *WiFi* I get this error:

[image]

i.e. when I execute `adb logcat -d | grep Wifi` it doesn't recognize the `grep` command. After removing `grep` it doesn't identify `Wifi`. And after removing `Wifi` it says that *"syntax is incorrect"*.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't `shell`-ed into the device so the `grep` command is executed in your host machine (Windows) environment. Execute `adb shell "logcat -d | grep Wifi"`.